# Why is my Php script redirecting user with /?

Tags: php

I have a script running on my site which is meant to redirect users who browser to '/' and then send them to 'www.' using a 302 redirect.

What I am confused about in Chrome is why it works but ends up sending them to...

http://www.example.com//

I downloaded the script and don't really understand it.... Basically I want the script to take anybody who is going to /site.com and redirect them using 302 to www.site.com

This is the script..

```
<?php

$protocol = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";

if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
    header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}

include_once("index/index.html");

?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: is the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] already a / then you are saying '/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] which would be 2 slashes

Comment: You can remove extra / by htaccess as well.

Comment: I don't know I downloaded the script and don't understand it.... Basically I want the script to take anybody who is going to /site.com and redirect them using 302 to www.site.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change your Code from**

`header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

**to**

`header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

As, you are adding an `extra forward slash`.

Hope, it helps.

Comment: Please Accept the answer, if it helped.

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorry for the delay I was waiting to implement and test to see if it worked (which it did) so thanks! :-)